# Is it valid to use company/year combinations for (financial) data analysis?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data, finance

I want do to a multiple regression analysis on some financial data. Sadly I only have 30 observations (the 30 different companies) and I would like to have more. My friend asked me why I don't add the observations for the last three years to the current one for each company so that I'd have 120 observations.

I wasn't sure what to reply, on the one hand that additional data might be great input cause the independent variables for each company change over time but on the other hand it feels wrong to mix years and companies in my analysis because then the several observations for each company could introduce bias into the analysis (e.g. if one company has very company specific outliers I would get 4 of these instead of just 1).

What do the experts on CrossValidated think?

Comment: Adding more years sounds like a good idea. Consider models for **[panel data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/panel-data/info)**. They explicitly account for the two dimensions of the dataset: the cross-sectional and the time-series one.

Comment: In your domain of study, panel data regressions are quite common!